# Errors when I send a comment with Laravel, Livewire and AlpineJS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a problem that I can't resolve.
I made a blog with Laravel 10, livewire 3, AlpineJS 3.

I'll show you my code.

Component livewire:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Livewire\Component;

class CommentCreate extends Component
{
    public string $content = '', $email = '', $nickname = '';

    public Post $post;

    public bool $creating = false;

    public function mount(Post $post, bool $creating = false, $parentComment = null)
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        $this->creating = $creating;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.comment-create');
    }

    private function resetInputFields()
    {
        $this->content = '';
        $this->email = '';
        $this->nickname = '';
    }

    public function createComment()
    {
        $comment = Comment::create([
            'content' => $this->content,
            'posts_id' => $this->post->id,
            'parent_id' => $this->parentComment?->id,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'nickname' => $this->nickname,
        ]);

        $this->resetInputFields();

        $this->dispatch('commentCreated', $comment->id);
    }
}
```

View livewire:

```
<div class="mb-5">
    <div x-data="{
        focused: {{ $creating ? 'true' : 'false' }},
        init() {
            $wire.on('commentCreated'), () => {
                this.focused = false;
            }
        }
    }">
        <button @click="focused = true" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
            Add comment
        </button>
        <div class="mt-5" :class="focused ? '' : 'd-none'">
            <input wire:model.live="nickname" class="form-control bg-white" type="text"
                placeholder="Pseudo" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
            <input wire:model.live="email" class="form-control bg-white mt-4" 
                type="email" placeholder="Email"
                aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
            <textarea wire:model.live="content" class="form-control bg-white mt-4" 
                rows="10"
                placeholder="Mettre un commentaire ici ..." aria-label="Text input with 
                dropdown button">
            </textarea>
            <div>
                <button wire:click='createComment' class="btn btn-primary mt-4" 
                    type="Submit">
                    <span class="text-white fw-semi-bold">Envoyer Commentaire</span>
                </button>
                <button @click="focused = false; isEdit = false; 
                    $wire.dispatch('cancelEditing')" type=button
                    class="btn btn-info mt-4">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the console of the browser I have multi errors everytime I try to click on send in add post. And the form doesn't collapse because I want this everytime someone send a comment.

[view of add comment and CRUD of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc4q6.png)

[view of errors in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHcDE.png)

I don't know what to try anymore.

Can you help me please ?

Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have a misplaced parenthesis, the initialization of the event listener should be:

```js
$wire.on('commentCreated', () => {
    this.focused = false;
})
```

Some magic properties may not be available in the *init()* function, you can try replacing *$wire* with *Livewire*:

```js
Livewire.on('commentCreated', () => {
```

but the shortest way to listen to a (custom) event is using *x-on* or its short hand notation *@*:

```html
<div x-data="{focused: {{ $creating ? 'true' : 'false' }}}"
     @comment-created.camel.window="focused = false"
>
```

Comment: Hi Pippo,

thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to find in a lot of place the answer and I couldn't find it.

Bye.